# Помогите инициализировать TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-textview

Итак, есть `layout`, содержащий 2 объекта — `RecycledView` и `TextView`. `RecyclerView` работает через адаптер, который передаёт значение в `TextView`. Выглядит это так. Фрагмент, содержащий `TextView`:

```
public class FragmentCharts extends Fragment {

//объявляем TextView
TextView chartDetailsHeader;

public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_charts, container, false);

    RecyclerView rationsChart = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rations_chart);
    rationsChart.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager rationsChartLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(
            getContext(),
            LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
            true);
    rationsChart.setLayoutManager(rationsChartLayoutManager);

    ChartAdapter chartAdapter = new ChartAdapter();
    rationsChart.setAdapter(chartAdapter);

    //инициализируем TextView
    chartDetailsHeader = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.chart_details_heading);
    chartDetailsHeader.setTypeface(CommonSettings.getRobotoCondLight());
    return view;
}

//метод для изменения значения TextView
public void setChartHeader(Date date) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM", Locale.US);
    String s = dateFormat.format(date);
    chartDetailsHeader.setText(s);
}
}
```

Изменение `TextView` происходит отправкой метода из адаптера:

```
new FragmentCharts().setChartHeader(archivesForCharts.get(0).get(0).getDate());
```

Как я понимаю, при создании `new FragmentCharts()` должна происходить инициализация `TextView`, но в методе `setChartHeader()` значение `TextView` почему-то `null`.

Пытался инициализировать `TextView` повторно в `setChartsHeader()`, но где взять `view` для инициализации?

В общем, как обычно, нужна помощь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш код `new FragmentCharts().setChartHeader(archivesForCharts.get(0).get(0).getDate());` каждый раз создаёт новый фрагмент. Но так как он ни куда не аттачится и не отображается, соответственно у него не вызываются никакие методы жизненного цикла, в том числе и `onCreateView`, в котором вы инициализируете `TextView`. Поэтому он и `null`.

Как решить? Не создавать новый объект фрагмента, а вызывать метод у существующего. То есть, например, добавить в конструктор адаптера параметр `FragmentCharts fragment`, и обращаться уже к нему. Во фрагменте у вас будет:

```
ChartAdapter chartAdapter = new ChartAdapter(this);
```

А в адапрере:

```
private FragmentCharts fragment;

public ChartAdapter(FragmentCharts fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
}
...
fragment.setChartHeader(archivesForCharts.get(0).get(0).getDate());
...
```